# Chaining Combine.Publisher and calling completion when finished

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to call several publishers in sequence and call the `completionBlock` when the last one is finished. All the return type of the publishers is `AnyPublisher<Void, Error>`. Compared to the solution below, can I do it with `.flatMap` or some other functions provided in `Publishers`?

```
private var firstObserver: AnyCancellable?
private var secondObserver: AnyCancellable?

public func setup() {
    firstObserver = Manager.firstPublisher()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in}, receiveValue: {[weak self] _ in
            self?.secondObserver = Manager.secondPublisher()
                .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in}, receiveValue: {[weak self] _ in
                    self?.completionBlock()
                }
        })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59615693/560942

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "in sequence". Publishers can emit multiple values over time. What do you consider a sequence in this case? Wait until the first publishers emits all values and completes, only then start the second one? Or start both simultaneously, and complete when all publishers complete?

Comment: This looks like a good `combineLatest` candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the publishers depend on each other, you should chain with `.flatMap`. If not, you could use `.append` instead. Either way, if all of these publishers are one-shot publishers (they all send a completion after one value), then the chain will be torn down in good order when all have fired.

Example 1:

```
    Just(1)
        .flatMap { Just(($0,2)) }
        .flatMap { Just(($0.0, $0.1, 3)) }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {print($0)},
              receiveValue: {print($0)})
        .store(in:&storage)
        // (1,2,3) as a tuple, then finished
```

Example 2:

```
    Just(1).append(Just(2).append(Just(3)))
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {print($0)},
              receiveValue: {print($0)})
        .store(in:&storage)
    // 1, then 2, then 3, then finished
```

Comment: According to your answer, shouldn't the comments for Example1 and Example2 be swapped?

Comment: I don’t see why...!